# C++ Error: Line 1440 Expression: string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, arrays

The program builds and runs, however after entering the first integer and pressing enter then the error pop up box appears, then after pressing ignore and entering the second integer and pressing enter the pop up box appears and after pressing ignore it returns the correct answer. I am at my wits end with this can somebody help me fix the pop up box thing.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define numbers 100

class largeintegers {
public:
    largeintegers();
    void
    Input();
    void
    Output();
    largeintegers
    operator+(largeintegers);
    largeintegers
    operator-(largeintegers);
    largeintegers
    operator*(largeintegers);
    int
    operator==(largeintegers);
private:
    int integer[numbers];
    int len;
};

void largeintegers::Output() {
    int i;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << integer[i];
}

void largeintegers::Input() {
    string in;
    int i, j, k;
    cout << "Enter any number:";
    cin >> in;
    for (i = 0; in[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    len = i;
    k = 0;
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        integer[j] = in[k++] - 48;
}

largeintegers::largeintegers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
        integer[i] = 0;
    len = numbers - 1;
}

int largeintegers::operator==(largeintegers op2) {
    int i;
    if (len < op2.len) return -1;
    if (op2.len < len) return 1;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (integer[i] < op2.integer[i])
            return -1;
        else if (op2.integer[i] < integer[i]) return 1;
    return 0;
}

largeintegers largeintegers::operator+(largeintegers op2) {
    largeintegers temp;
    int carry = 0;
    int c, i;
    if (len > op2.len)
        c = len;
    else
        c = op2.len;

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        temp.integer[i] = integer[i] + op2.integer[i] + carry;
        if (temp.integer[i] > 9) {
            temp.integer[i] %= 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else
            carry = 0;
    }
    if (carry == 1) {
        temp.len = c + 1;
        if (temp.len >= numbers)
            cout << "***OVERFLOW*****\n";
        else
            temp.integer[i] = carry;

    } else
        temp.len = c;
    return temp;
}
largeintegers largeintegers::operator-(largeintegers op2) {
    largeintegers temp;
    int c;
    if (len > op2.len)
        c = len;
    else
        c = op2.len;
    int borrow = 0;
    for (int i = c; i >= 0; i--)
        if (borrow == 0) {
            if (integer[i] >= op2.integer[i])
                temp.integer[i] = integer[i] - op2.integer[i];
            else {
                borrow = 1;
                temp.integer[i] = integer[i] + 10 - op2.integer[i];
            }
        } else {
            borrow = 0;
            if (integer[i] - 1 >= op2.integer[i])
                temp.integer[i] = integer[i] - 1 - op2.integer[i];
            else {
                borrow = 1;
                temp.integer[i] = integer[i] - 1 + 10 - op2.integer[i];
            }
        }
    temp.len = c;
    return temp;
}
largeintegers largeintegers::operator*(largeintegers op2) {
    largeintegers temp;
    int i, j, k, tmp, m = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < op2.len; i++) {
        k = i;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            tmp = integer[j] * op2.integer[i];
            temp.integer[k] = temp.integer[k] + tmp;
            temp.integer[k + 1] = temp.integer[k + 1] + temp.integer[k] / 10;
            temp.integer[k] %= 10;
            k++;
            if (k > m) m = k;
        }
    }
    temp.len = m;
    if (temp.len > numbers) cout << "***OVERFLOW*****\n";
    return temp;
}

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int c;
    largeintegers num1, num2, result;
    num1.Input();
    num2.Input();
    num1.Output();
    cout << " + ";
    num2.Output();
    result = num1 + num2;
    cout << " = ";
    result.Output();
    cout << "\n\n";
    num1.Output();
    cout << " - ";
    num2.Output();
    result = num1 - num2;
    cout << " = ";
    result.Output();
    cout << "\n\n";
    num1.Output();
    cout << " * ";
    num2.Output();
    result = num1 * num2;
    cout << " = ";
    result.Output();
    cout << "\n\n";
    c = num1 == num2;
    num1.Output();
    switch (c) {
    case -1:
        cout << " is less than ";
        break;
    case 0:
        cout << " is equal to ";
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << " is greater than ";
        break;
    }
    num2.Output();
    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Hope this is a copy paste issue and not the way your code looks.. else, learn to love indentation

Comment: @KarthikT Presumably it says what he put in the question title.

Comment: I don't feel like counting. Which is line 1440? You didn't post that many lines (thankfully).

Comment: Have you tried a [debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx)? ("popup" makes me assume you're running Windows.)

Comment: Just a guess but I don't think there are 1440 lines

Comment: C++ Error: Line 1440 Expression: string subscript out of range

Comment: On line 1440, what's the value of the subscript, and how long is the string? Is the former bigger than the latter? Why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are falling victim to the difference between C-style strings and C++ strings.  C-style strings are a series of `char`s followed by a zero (or null) byte.  C++ strings are objects that contain a series of characters (usually char, but eventually this will be an assumption you should break) and that know their own length.  C++ strings can contain null bytes in the middle of themselves without problem.

To loop through all of the characters of a C++-style string, you can do one of a number of things:

- You can use the `.size()` or `.length()` members of a `string` variable to find the number of characters in it, as in `for (int i=0; i<str.size(); i++) { char c = str[i];`
- You can use `.begin()` and `.end()` to get iterators to the beginning and end of the string, respectively.  A for loop in the form `for (std::string::iterator it=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)` will loop you through the members of the string by accessing `*it`.
- If you're using C++11, you can use the for loop construct as follows: `for (auto c: str)` where `c` will be of the type of a character of the string `str`.

In the future, to solve problems like these, you can try using the debugger to see what happens when your program crashes or hits an exception.  You likely would find that inside of `largeintegers::Input()` you running into either a memory access violation or some other problem.

Finally, as a future-looking criticism, you should not use C-style arrays (where you say `int integer[ numbers ];`) in favor of using C++-style containers, such as `vector`.  A `vector` is a series of objects (such as `int`s) that can expand as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am  beginner in C++ and sometimes things get a bit confusing.